# Copy multiple directory using hadoop command

Tags: hadoop

I know that hadoop has capability to copy multiple directory at the same time to common target path by using following command :-

```
hadoop fs -cp dir1 dir2 dir3 target
```

but i want to know that what is the max number of directory or files that i can copy simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Copying directories does not have any limitations (You can think of **Integer.MAX_VALUE**). The files, directories and blocks in HDFS are stored in **Namenode** memory.

But there is limit of hardware you would be using , Scaling up much beyond the hardware limit is the problem here.

Comment: when i am trying the above command , i am getting multiple logs for single file but not in sequence.like "/hc/hive/db_gold/hct_gold_cisco_wifi_absence_denorm/trans_hr=2017022823/load_hr=2017032020/000000_0' is not open."

Comment: Can you show us full log, and update above in post it will be easy to explain the cause , with what you are trying.

Comment: Is there any other way to copy multiple directory at same time on hdfs.?